Loss of Polygons on QGIS 3.28
I have recently saved a QGIS project with about 1200 polygons representing historic field boundaries. The attribute table contains such information as size, owner code, tenure,parcel number and description. I reloaded the project yesterday and most of the polygons in this layer have disappeared! Their values in the attribute table are still there, but no polygons are drawn for most of the layer - just for the first 20 or so in the attribute table. The layer is an shp file.
I have tried exporting the layer to a different format to no avail. The same polygons are missing.
Prior to this loss I had duplicated this layer but changed the properties and labels in the duplicate to show a different attribute of each polygon (The tenure of each field). This layer, based on the first has the same problem but with different polygons missing.
Are the polygons retrieveable? Is this a known problem with QGIS 3.28. I have no backup (yes....I know....).
I am a new QGIS user.

This could have different reason, we could just starting to guess... If you duplicate a layer, it is based on the same datasource as the initial layer. So changes you make on the duplicated layer affect also the data of the initial layer. Did you set a filter (there are different places where you can apply filters)? Can you share the data for testing? As mentioned, there are dozens of possible explanations, and before we start to check them all, it's easier to check to file to see how many geometries you have.

Otherwise: open a new, empty QGIS project, drag and drop the Shapefile to this window. Do not change anything: how many polygons do you have? Also: you mentioned you have saved the QGIS  project. Did you also save the changes you made in the layer? Did you create the polygons or did you get the layer from somewhere?

Thanks Babel. How much of the data would you wish to see. Just the polygon layers affected? How might I share these?

Yes, share the polygon layer only: upload to a cloud and share the link here. Be aware: Shapefiles consist of not just one, but of normally like 3 to 6 separate files. Share all of them.

Ok. Will do a little later. Thanks.

This is the link to the polygon layer. three files. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/i8675deth81zacd2l8p87/ALP_oXirna-ImgWUoaey8B4?rlkey=0w4mi6svevispgufnvlsgt1px&dl=0

Indeed: in the file you shared, only 83 out of 1264 features contain a geometry (polygon), the other features consist of attribute values only. To see what happened, you should provide more details and describe step  by step what you did. By the way, your file came without a CRS definition, I had to set it to British national grid.

Thanks. I duplicated the layer in order to show, by colour and label, a different attributs of the polygons. In the layer I have shared, I showed the owner code or the description, depending on what I wished to display. In the duplicated layer I wished to show, as mentioned above, the tenure. Prior to this I hade tried to use the layer I have shared by filtering for tenure in the attributes table. I corrected several typos and saved them in the attribute table. It was all working fine - the two layers could be displayed together or separately. I saved them as I made changes.

Before I closed down QGis i saved each layer I was editing in turn by toggling the edit off and saving when prompted. I then selected "Exit QGIS" and the program, after a few seconds, closed. IWhen I opened QGiS the next day, the files had many polygons missing as you can see. Thanks again.

I had created the polygons myself, manually tracing over a raster image of a map, adding the attributes as I went along. I had to correct the georeferencing of some parts of the raster map and was realigning the polygons to fit the new image.

Please [Edit] the Question to describe your steps. It's impossible to read a litany of comments.

So then something went wrong when you created the polygons, it seems they were not saved. From far and without knowing what you did it's impossible to say. By the way: why do you use Shapefiles? Nowadays, if you work in QGIS, you should use Geopackage: http://switchfromshapefile.org/#geopackage
